# Trasparent Background in Mono c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, mono

How do I get a transparent background in Raspbian?

I have already tried

```
this.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
this.TrasparencyKey = Color.Yellow;
```

Comment: Your question is a little light on details.   Is this Winforms on Raspbian?  Winforms was already pretty dicey at supporting transparency anyway.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Winforms on mono

Comment: edit your question to include the word "WinForms" then, please